# reRender a rich:dataTable cell in a Seam page from another page

Tags: richfaces, seam2

I´m trying to use reRender on a richFaces commandButton to update a single cell column from a dataTable in another window, to no success. Here´s a snippet:

---

**page1.xhtml**

```
<rich:column columnId="anotacoes" 
columnHeader="Anotações"
columnWidth="10%"
hideOrder="true">
    <a:form>
        <a:region renderRegionOnly="true">  
            <s:link view="page2.seam"
                    onclick="openPopUp('#{row}popUpAnotacao', '');"
                    target="#{row}popUpAnotacao">                           
                    </s:link>                                                                 
            <div id="reRenderHere">
                    <h:outputText 
                     value="#{row.resumoUltimaAnotacao}"/></div>
        </a:region>     
     </a:form>
```

**page2.xhtml**

```
<a:commandButton id="saveAba"
 action="#{bean.inserirAnotacao()}"  
 value="Salvar"
 reRender="pageBody" />
```

So, page1 has a table with links in each row, which opens page2 in a popup window. In page2 we can save some data, which should be shown inside the "reRenderHere" div when we press the commandButton. I want to be able to update just the cell which was modified, without refreshing all the table rows neither losing track of the current page (the table has pagination).

I´ve tried to use reRender with ":form:table:row" as parameter, with no success. My guess is that page2 can´t access the DOM in page1, I don´t know for sure.

I´m using RichFaces 3 and Seam 2 (Yeah, i know.)

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a modal panel instead?

Comment: It´s a legacy system, it was designed that way. My team has been supporting it (mostly fixing bugs) since january, and we are still learning about it.